# Next.js navbar: highlighting doesn't clear when clicking on link from different <nav> group

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap, next-router

I'm trying to implement a navbar with active links highlighting with Next.js (I am using React-bootstrap, too, for the record).

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262263/target-active-link-when-the-route-is-active-in-next-js) guide, and some highlighting works, while other doesn't.

**My Current Code**:

CustomLink.jsx:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { Children } from 'react';

const CustomLink = ({ children, activeClassName, ...props }) => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  const child = Children.only(children);
  const childClassName = child.props.className || '';

  const className =
    asPath === props.href || asPath === props.as
      ? `${childClassName} ${activeClassName}`.trim()
      : childClassName;

  return (
    <Link {...props} passHref>
      {React.cloneElement(child, {
        className: className || null,
      })}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default CustomLink;
```

Navigation.jsx:

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import CustomLink from '../CustomLink/CustomLink';

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <CustomLink activeClassName="active" href="/">
          <img src="/logo.svg" alt="WhiteQueen Logo" height={50} />
        </CustomLink>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <CustomLink activeClassName="active" href="/">
              <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
            </CustomLink>
            <CustomLink activeClassName="active" href="/publications">
              <Nav.Link>Publications</Nav.Link>
            </CustomLink>
            <CustomLink activeClassName="active" href="/links">
              <Nav.Link>Links</Nav.Link>
            </CustomLink>
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
            <CustomLink activeClassName="active" href="/contact">
              <Nav.Link>Contact</Nav.Link>
            </CustomLink>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}
```

**My issue:**

Clicking on any link on the left-side of the navbar works correctly, meaning it highlights the selected link **and** clears the previous one. **But** that's only true when cycling between "Home", "Publications" and "Links".

If I click on the link on the right hand side ("Contact") **or** on the logo, the current active class of, say, "Publications" isn't cleared and both (previously active and currently selected) show as highlighted.

Similarly, if I am on "Contact", going to any item of the other group doesn't clear its highlighting.

Links revert to highlighting correctly if I refresh the page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does clicking on "Contact" cause a re-render of the `CustomLink`s on the other group?

Comment: No, no link causes a re-render. They work fine in that respect.

Comment: That's probably why the highlighting doesn't update.

Comment: No, no. I think I got what it is. I'll add my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as an answer hoping it may be of help to others with this issue, and I believe I know what was producing the issue:

I was adding (and styling) the activeClassName "active".

Incidentally, that's the same className Nav.Link (React-bootstrap) adds.

So in fact my code was working correctly in adding and deleting the active classname, but it was duplicate with React-bootstrap's and my custom Link was only removing one of them, not the Bootstrap one.

My solution was to use a different activeClassName ("is-active", for example) and now it all works as it's supposed to.