# How to style an active Link for a mapped NavBar

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm making a page in NextJs, and would love to show the user which page they're on with some styling of the NavBar.

This seems super -
[Target Active Link when the route is active in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262263/target-active-link-when-the-route-is-active-in-next-js)
...however I'm using a mapped list to generate the NavBar.

Might anyone be able to help me out with how to use this with a map() function please?
Here's my code, which works otherwise.

```
import Link from "next/link";

import styles from "../NavBarDesktop/NavBarDesktop.module.css";

import ButtonBase from "../button/buttonPrimary";
import MenuItems from "../../../data/MenuItems/MenuItems";

const NavBarDesktop = () => {

  return (
    <div className={styles.navBar}>
      <ul className={styles.navMenu}>
        {MenuItems.map((item) => (
          <li className={styles.navItem} key={item.id}>
            <Link href={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBarDesktop;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you posted, this wouldn't be any different when using map. All the `map` function is doing is looping over your `MenuItems`.

What you would need to do is check to see if the current `item` is the one you're looking at within your map callback function.

An example of what you could do:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const NavBarDesktop = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className={styles.navBar}>
      <ul className={styles.navMenu}>
        {MenuItems.map((item) => {
          const activeStyle = item.path === router.pathname ? styles.activeNavItem : '';
          
          return (
            <li className={`${styles.navItem} ${activeStyle}`} key={item.id} >
              <Link href={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What I'm doing here is checking to see if the `item.path` matches Next.js `router.pathname`. I use `next/router` because this should match up with what you are trying to use with `Link`. If they do match, then I want the current nav item that we are looking at to be the active one and so we add it as a class to your `li` element.

More info on next/router here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object

You might need to play around with this to make sure it does match with what your `href` is.